# How to disable alphanumeric sender ID for Messaging Services

Tags: sms, twilio

I have a Messaging Service with the following configuration:

- Use case defines as `Notifications, 2-Way`
- `Request url` in Inbound Settings section is defined
- `Alpha Sender ID` in `Copilot Features` section is not enabled
- Single phone number from USA is assigned to this Messaging Service

Now, when I send sms to the phone number from USA, I see it as sent from the phone number assigned to this Messaging Service. However when I send sms to the phone number from Poland (Europe) I receive it as it would've been sent with `SMS` alphanumeric sender ID and as a receiver of this message I'm not able to reply to this message.

I would like to disable alphanumeric sender ID completely and always send sms as it would've been sent from regular phone number from USA.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a carrier issue rather than your configuration settings.

From [this page](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181088-Why-do-some-SMS-recipients-see-a-Sender-ID-that-is-not-my-Twilio-number-) on the Twilio web site:

> Some carriers in certain countries will block SMS that are sent from
>   foreign phone numbers. To make sure your messages get through, the
>   Sender ID of a message may sometimes be modified to a format that will
>   be accepted by the carrier of the mobile device.
>
> Messages where the Sender ID was modified hence do not support 2-way
>   communication as replies from recipients will not be routed back to
>   your Twilio number.

Personally I would add a Polish number to my Twilio account.

I would do that even if I wasn't having this problem. As a client I would have much more confidence in replying to a national number over an international one.

Clients may think international text rates are higher (which they might be) and this will also reduce your response rate.